# Using XSL, I need to check links' href value and change if necessary while leaving other attributes alone

Tags: html, xslt

The following code does the following:

1. Finds links
2. Checks to see if it's a fully pathed link or an email link
3. If yes, it does nothing.
4. If no, it checks for a # to see if it's an anchor
5. If yes, it does nothing.
6. If no, it concatenates the domain in front.

This works, but if I add another attribute to the link, it strips it out as well.  For example: `<a href="/myfile.html" style="color:white">My link</a>`

How do I keep the behavior below but also keep the style attribute?

```
<xsl:template match="a[@href][not(contains(@href, 'http')) and not(contains(@href, 'mailto'))]">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(@href, '#')">
                <a href="{@href}" ><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <a href="{concat($domain, @href)}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing input, current XSLT and expected output.

Comment: Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="a[@href][not(contains(@href, 'http')) and not(contains(@href, 'mailto'))]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(@href, '#'))">
                <xsl:value-of select="$domain" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or possibly just:

```
<xsl:template match="a/@href[not(contains(., 'http') or contains(., 'mailto') or starts-with(., '#'))]">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="$domain" />
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested, because no example was provided.